# Checking to see if a binary search tree is degenerate

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I want to check if a binary search tree is degenerate or not (Is it a linked list or indeed a tree?) I've been trying for a while and have come up with nothing that works. I did come up with a nonrecursive solution which I thought was quite clever but the specifications state it has to be a recursive solution and I'm having translating it from non-recursive to recursive.

Here's my non-recursive solution (well not really because size and height are both implemented recursively. This method however is not).

```
public boolean isDegenerate(){
        if(this.size() == this.getHeight()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a good homework problem, so I'd rather not put the answer online, ruining a good question for posterity. But have you thought about just counting the number of children of each node recursively? What do you know about the tree based on the child count of the current node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want a "more recursive" solution, how about this?

```
public boolean isDegenerate() {
    if (this.left != null) {
        if (this.right != null) {
            return false; // not degenerate, has two children
        } else {
            return this.left.isDegenerate();
        }
    } else {
        if (this.right != null) {
            return this.right.isDegenerate();
        } else {
            return true; // we arrived at the bottom without seeing any node with two children
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws a nullpointer for me. I don't think the case where this == null is being taken care of.

Comment: `this` can never be null. Maybe you need to take care of the case when there are no tree nodes at all (not even root).